# Retrieving an array of numbers from MonoDB with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How do I properly retrieve an array of numbers from MongoDB Collection Object with meteor.js?
In the code, my `alert(temp)` suppose to output a number that is added up like 5.95+5.95+5.95 = 17.85, but the output is `0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]`, which means I did not properly convert the object to number format. Please show me how to covert the object into numbers that i can add them up.

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.price6.events({
 'click a': function () {            // in my page, i clicked this multiple times to insert 3 time 5.95 into the Mongodb object.
    Tasks.insert({
            text: 5.95,            
            createdAt: new Date() // current time
    });
  }
});
Meteor.methods({
  GetTotal: function () {
     var postsArray = Tasks.find().fetch(); // it will fetch the numbers into an array according to the meteor.js doc
     var temp = 0.00;
     for    (index = 0; index < postsArray.length; index++) {
            temp += postsArray[index];
     }
     alert(temp);//suppose to be a number but the output result is weird 0[object][object].....
  },  
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler inserts into the `Tasks` collection objects that look like this:

```
{
  text: 5.95,            
  createdAt: new Date() // current time
}
```

When you retrieve the records back, the "text" (that's a misleading name if you only store numbers in that property) will be a key of each element of the `Tasks.find().fetch()` array, so add `.text` to your code:

```
for (index = 0; index < postsArray.length; index++) {
  temp += parseFloat(postsArray[index].text);
}
```

Comment: The .text thing fixed the [Object] thing and out put numbers now, but it is 05.955.955.95.95  How can I actually add them up instead of lining them up?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I need to use parseFloat() to convert it.